# SwiftUI with NotificationCenter publishers

Tags: swiftui, combine, notificationcenter

I want to listen to notifications when the app goes to the background and comes back. I'm trying to use the NotificationCenter publishers and have the SwiftUI view listen to them.
I can use a few methods to do it and I'm trying to use two of them but the interesting thing is, that although all seem legit when I put the subscriber in the `init()` method, it just does not work. 
I tried to put it on the `main` thread but still no success.
Does anyone have any idea why?
Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isActive = true
    @State var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)                        
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
            self.isActive = false
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification), perform: {_ in
            self.isActive = true
        })
    }

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)
         //   .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                print("init")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Strangely the listener in the `onReceive` modifier works like a charm. In the `init()` the `print("init")` never gets called.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@State` is not ready yet in init, so it cannot be used for such purposes. The approach can be as follows:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)
        .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
            print(">> in init")
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

in such defined `cancellables` you can store all subscribers created in `init`, but you will not be able to use it later in code, but this approach is good for once defined notification handlers.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem. I did not want the `@State` wrapper anyway but at a certain point Xcode started complaining that in a struct you can't modify the properties. But now it accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `onAppear`?

```
...
...
  var body: some View {
  ... your body code
  }.onAppear(perform: loadNotification)

  private func loadNotification() {
     NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
     ....
  }
```

See `onAppear`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278614-onappear

It seems to be the replacement for `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I think it is more like the `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Will this be called multiple times? If so the action will also be triggered multiple times